# Angular2: using md-progress-circle

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I'm trying to use md-progress-circle on my Angular2 app. I have a login form component, and when user press login, i would show progress circle over form until login is completed (and centered).
This is my code:

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div style="width:400px;text-align:center">
    <md-progress-circle mode="indeterminate" color="primary" *ngIf="showSpinner">

         <!-- my code for login form -->
    </md-progress-circle>

</div>
</div>
```

Now if i launch app, i can't see login form. 
md-progress-circle goes over my login form, in fact, if i remove *ngIf condition, i can see oonly circle, but no form.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the login form inside `md-progress-circle`, thats why it is not visible. Any content in between `<md-progress-circle></md-progress-circle>` tag will be ignored by the component. You should keep the login form and `md-progress-circle` separate like this,

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div style="width:400px;text-align:center">
    <md-progress-circle mode="indeterminate" 
                        color="primary" 
                        *ngIf="showSpinner">
    </md-progress-circle>
    <div *ngIf="!showSpinner">
         <!-- my code for login form -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to show progress over login form ?

Comment: You can display the progress circle over (on top of) login form by using suitable CSS position for progress circle and removing `*ngIf` from the login form.